# Perl 5.10 - POSIX Signals ignored unless received during sleep() call?

Tags: perl, unix

I'm running into a bit of an issue when it comes to how Perl handles POSIX signals.  Namely, Perl seems to ignore the signals unless they're received during a call to `sleep()`.

For example, the following code works fine:

```
#/usr/bin/perl
$SIG{PIPE} = sub { print STDERR "WARNING: Received SIGPIPE"; exit(1); };
while (1) { print "Waiting on signal...\n"; sleep(10); }
```

When using the above SIGPIPE handler in another script which reads from an Oracle database, the subroutine never seems to get called.

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

$SIG{PIPE} = sub { print STDERR "WARNING: Received SIGPIPE"; exit(1); };

my $db = "redacted";
my $user = "redacted";
my $pass = "redacted";
my $table = "redacted";

my $ora = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:" . $db, $user, $pass);
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
my $query = $ora->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

while (my @row = $query->fetchrow_array()) {
    print(join('|', @row) . "\n");
}

if ( $DBI::err ) { print STDERR "ERROR: Unload terminated due to error"; }
```

I'm sending the SIGPIPE signal to both scripts in the same manner (`kill -sPIPE pid`), but only the first script responds to it.  The second script simply carries on.  No message, no exit, nothing.

How can I rectify this situation?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Is it possible that the Oracle driver is trying to use `$SIG{PIPE}` too? Check the value of `$SIG{PIPE}` before and after your `execute` call.

Comment: I'm getting the same code hash before/after the call to execute.  Just to make sure the value is being set, I also had it print the value before setting the handler (it was updated as expected).  To complicate the matters, adding a `sleep(30)` before the processing loop allows it to catch the signal, but only during the duration of the sleep.

Comment: Reads don't generate SIGPIPE; you get SIGPIPE when you try to write to a pipe or socket where there is no receiver process.

Comment: Note that signal handlers are only called between Perl instructions. If one comes in during the execution a Perl instruction (including a call to a C database driver library function), the signal handler will be called after the instruction is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the signal handler before the DBI calls somehow leads it to being ignored after some of the DBI methods are called.  The solution was to move the signal handler subroutine to just before the processing loop, but after the call to execute:

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

# SIGPIPE handler used to be here

my $db = "redacted";
my $user = "redacted";
my $pass = "redacted";
my $table = "redacted";

my $ora = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:" . $db, $user, $pass);
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table;
my $query = $ora->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

$SIG{PIPE} = sub { print STDERR "WARNING: Received SIGPIPE"; exit(1); };

while (my @row = $query->fetchrow_array()) {
    print(join('|', @row) . "\n");
}

if ( $DBI::err ) { print STDERR "ERROR: Unload terminated due to error"; }
```

I'm not exactly sure why it fixes the issue, but it does.

Comment: More evidence for my theory that the (Perl) db code sets a SIGPIPE handler (even if it doesn't change `$SIG{PIPE}`).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the DBI driver being used to communicate with the database is written in XS code. XS code that is going to block for a long time has to be carefully written to cope with signals and perl's "safe signals" delivery system. It is possible that the DB driver you are using doesn't take account of this, and therefore won't work.